# Having issues with or_gam function in oddsratio package

Tags: r, linear-regression, spline, gam, mgcv

#### Data

Here is the `dput` of my data:

```
heart <- structure(list(died = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Survive", 
"Died"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "Death", format = "%8.0g", value.label.table = structure(0:1, names = c("Survive", 
"Died"))), procedure = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("PTCA", 
"CABG"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "1=CABG; 0=PTCA", format = "%8.0g", value.label.table = structure(0:1, names = c("PTCA", 
"CABG"))), age = structure(c(65L, 69L, 76L, 65L, 69L, 67L, 69L, 
66L, 74L, 67L, 76L, 76L, 68L, 77L, 77L, 70L, 68L, 69L, 68L, 70L, 
71L, 75L, 69L, 72L, 66L, 77L, 68L, 78L, 77L, 69L, 65L, 70L, 65L, 
70L), label = "PATIENT AGE", class = c("labelled", "integer"), format = "%8.0g"), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Female", 
    "Male"), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = "Gender", format = "%8.0g", value.label.table = structure(0:1, names = c("Female", 
    "Male"))), los = structure(c(10L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 
    9L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 
    12L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), label = "LOS", class = c("labelled", 
    "integer"), format = "%8.0g"), type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), levels = c("Elective", "Emer/Urg"), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = "Severity", format = "%8.0g", value.label.table = structure(0:1, names = c("Elective", 
    "Emer/Urg")))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), stata.info = list(datalabel = "AZ 1991; CABG(106,107) & PTCA(112)", 
    version = 12L, time.stamp = "17 Feb 2015 12:45", val.labels = c("diedlb", 
    "pxllb", "", "sexllb", "", "typellb"), label.table = list(
        pxllb = structure(0:1, names = c("PTCA", "CABG")), typellb = structure(0:1, names = c("Elective", 
        "Emer/Urg")), sexllb = structure(0:1, names = c("Female", 
        "Male")), diedlb = structure(0:1, names = c("Survive", 
        "Died")))))
```

#### Problem

So far I have fit multiple models like this using tensor splines to encode main and interaction effects:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(oddsratio)
library(mgcv)
library(splines)
library(tidyverse)

#### Fit GAM With Tensor Splines ####
fit <- gam(factor(died) 
          ~ ti(age)
          + ti(los)
          + ti(age,los),
          data = heart,
          family = binomial)
```

However, when I try to plot the main effects:

```
plot_gam(model = fit,
         pred = "age")
```

I get this odd warning:

```
Error in plot_df[[set_pred]]$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I tried calling the function `plot_gam` explicitly, which look like this, but I'm a bit fuzzy on why this code is causing the issue. Calling whatever `gam_to_df` is also didn't seem to clarify the problem:

```
function (model = NULL, pred = NULL, col_line = "blue", ci_line_col = "black", 
    ci_line_type = "dashed", ci_fill = "grey", ci_alpha = 0.4, 
    ci_line_size = 0.8, sm_fun_size = 1.1, title = NULL, xlab = NULL, 
    ylab = NULL, limits_y = NULL, breaks_y = NULL) 
{
    df <- gam_to_df(model, pred)
    if (is.null(xlab)) {
        xlab <- df[[pred]]$xlab
    }
    if (is.null(ylab)) {
        ylab <- df[[pred]]$ylab
    }
    plot_gam <- ggplot(df, aes_(~x, ~y)) + geom_line(colour = col_line, 
        size = sm_fun_size) + geom_line(aes_(~x, ~se_upr), linetype = ci_line_type, 
        colour = ci_line_col, size = ci_line_size) + geom_line(aes_(~x, 
        ~se_lwr), linetype = ci_line_type, colour = ci_line_col, 
        size = ci_line_size) + geom_ribbon(aes_(x = ~x, ymin = ~se_lwr, 
        ymax = ~se_upr), fill = ci_fill, alpha = ci_alpha) + 
        ylab(ylab) + xlab(xlab)
    if (!is.null(limits_y) & !is.null(breaks_y)) {
        plot_gam <- plot_gam + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(breaks_y), 
            limits = c(limits_y))
    }
    else if (!is.null(limits_y) & is.null(breaks_y)) {
        plot_gam <- plot_gam + scale_y_continuous(limits = limits_y)
    }
    else if (is.null(limits_y) & !is.null(breaks_y)) {
        plot_gam <- plot_gam + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(breaks_y))
    }
    if (!is.null(title)) {
        plot_gam <- plot_gam + ggtitle(title)
    }
    return(plot_gam)
}
```

I would greatly appreciate a resolution to this issue. The `plot_gam` function is super useful for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was inspecting the code. Error is caused by a fairly naïve implementation of `oddsratio::gam_to_df` function.

```
gam_to_df <- function (model = NULL, pred = NULL) 
{
  plot_df <- no_plot(model)
  set_pred <- grep(paste0("\\b", pred, "\\b"), plot_df)
  df <- data.frame(x = plot_df[[set_pred]]$x, se_upr = plot_df[[set_pred]]$fit + 
    plot_df[[set_pred]]$se, se_lwr = plot_df[[set_pred]]$fit - 
    plot_df[[set_pred]]$se, y = plot_df[[set_pred]]$fit)
  return(df)
}
no_plot <- function (model = NULL) 
{
  png("temp.xyz")
  plot_df <- plot(model, pages = 1)
  dev.off()
  file.remove("temp.xyz")
  return(invisible(plot_df))
}
```

The function first create a plot and return it (it is a list) then extract the element that contains "age" somewhere in one of the elements, searching it via grep. Since two of three elements contains "age" it returns  a vector of two elelments c(1,3). Thus `plot_df[[set_pred]]` instead of selecting the first element, selects the first of the list and then the third element inside of the list, which is a vector.
Hence the error "operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Appears to be a bug.

**EDIT**
Filled an issue at https://github.com/pat-s/oddsratio/issues/54

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a dummy here, but how would you run the function here on the model? I tried using `no_plot(model=fit)` after running your code chunk and it didn't do anything from what I could tell.

Comment: Relevant code is in `gam_to_df` from which no_plot is a dependency

Comment: Thanks for clarifying as well as reporting the bug.